# NVDA Screen Reader not reading text within of Dialog Box?

Tags: html, model-view-controller

Below mentioned code reflects a 'Dialog' on screen.I am using NVDA screen Reader to read screen. When Dialog box is opened,the focus shown on only input buttons and  Screen Reader reads only Input buttons.
But I want that screen reader should read H2 Heading text and also other text "Are you sure want to *****". I am using MVC. So please can anyone assist me that how can we read whole text within dialog box?

```
<div id="completCheckInLayer">
            <div class="ui-dialog-content  ui-widget-content">

                <div id="CompleteCheckInhelpLayerContent" class="complete-checkin-content">
                    <h2  class="help-layer-heading" > <span class="accessibleText"> Beginning of Dialog</span>
                        Confirm Completion Without Printing</h2>
                    <div class="check-in-complete-help-layer-content">
                        Are you sure you want to ******And Some More Text here*****
                    <div class="center">
                        <span id="Span1" class="DCLButton"><span class="DCLButtonInner">
                            <form action="/FormPrint.aspx" target="_blank" method="get">
                            <input value="Print Form" type="submit" id="confirmationLayerPrintButton" />
                            </form>
                        </span></span><span id="Span2" class="DCLButton blueShadowButton help-layer-complete-checkin-button">
                            <span class="DCLButtonInner">
                                <input value="Continue Without Printing" type="submit" id="confirmationLayerCompleteCheckInButton" />
                            </span></span>
                            <span class="accessibleText"> End of Dialog</span>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
```